# How to debug layout performance problems in WPF?

Tags: wpf, performance, user-interface, drawing

I'm writing a custom control for WPF (a drawn one) and I'm having massive performance issues. The fact is that I'm drawing a lots of text and this might be a part of the problem. I timed the OnRender method however, and I'm faced with very weird results - the whole method (especially after moving to GlyphRun implemenation) takes around 2-3ms to complete. Everything looks like following (take a look at the Output window for debug timing results) (requires Flash to play):

https://www.screencast.com/t/5p6mC6rxFv0

The OnRender method doesn't have anything special in particular, it just renders some rectangles and text:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        ValidateMetrics();

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        var pixelsPerDip = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).PixelsPerDip;

        // Draw header
        DrawHeader(drawingContext, pixelsPerDip);

        // Draw margin
        DrawMargin(drawingContext, pixelsPerDip);

        // Draw data
        DrawData(drawingContext, pixelsPerDip);

        // Draw footer
        DrawFooter(drawingContext);

        stopwatch.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Drawing took {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
```

I ran Visual Studio's performance analysis and got the following results:

[image: Performance analysis results]

Clearly "Layout" of the editor control takes a lot of time, but still rendering is very quick.

How to debug this performance issue further? Why performance is so low despite OnRender taking milliseconds to run?

---

**Edit** - as response to comments

I didn't find a good way to time drawing, though I found, what was the cause of the problem and it turned out to be text drawing. I ended up with using very low-level text drawing mechanism, using GlyphRuns and it turned out to be fast enough to display full HD worth of text at least 30 frames per second, what was enough for me.

I'll post some relevant pieces of code below. Please note though: this is not ready-to-use solution, but should point anyone interested in the right direction.

```cs
private class GlyphRunInfo
{
    public GlyphRunInfo()
    {
        CurrentPosition = 0;
    }

    public void FillMissingAdvanceWidths()
    {
        while (AdvanceWidths.Count < GlyphIndexes.Count)
            AdvanceWidths.Add(0);
    }

    public List<ushort> GlyphIndexes { get; } = new List<ushort>();
    public List<double> AdvanceWidths { get; } = new List<double>();
    public double CurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public double? StartPosition { get; set; }
}

// (...)

private void BuildTypeface()
{
    typeface = new Typeface(FontFamily);
    if (!typeface.TryGetGlyphTypeface(out glyphTypeface))
    {
        typeface = null;
        glyphTypeface = null;
    }
}

private void AddGlyph(char c, double position, GlyphRunInfo info)
{
    if (glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap.TryGetValue(c, out ushort glyphIndex))
    {
        info.GlyphIndexes.Add(glyphIndex);
        if (info.GlyphIndexes.Count > 1)
            info.AdvanceWidths.Add(position - info.CurrentPosition);
        info.CurrentPosition = position;
        if (info.StartPosition == null)
            info.StartPosition = info.CurrentPosition;
    }
}

private void DrawGlyphRun(DrawingContext drawingContext, GlyphRunInfo regularRun, Brush brush, double y, double pixelsPerDip)
{
    if (regularRun.StartPosition != null)
    {
        var glyphRun = new GlyphRun(glyphTypeface,
            bidiLevel: 0,
            isSideways: false,
            renderingEmSize: FontSize,
            pixelsPerDip: (float)pixelsPerDip,
            glyphIndices: regularRun.GlyphIndexes,
            baselineOrigin: new Point(Math.Round(regularRun.StartPosition.Value),
                Math.Round(glyphTypeface.Baseline * FontSize + y)),
            advanceWidths: regularRun.AdvanceWidths,
            glyphOffsets: null,
            characters: null,
            deviceFontName: null,
            clusterMap: null,
            caretStops: null,
            language: null);

        drawingContext.DrawGlyphRun(brush, glyphRun);
    }
}
```

And then some random code, which used the prior methods:

```cs
var regularRun = new GlyphRunInfo();
var selectionRun = new GlyphRunInfo();

// (...)

for (int ch = 0, index = line * Document.BytesPerRow; ch < charPositions.Count && index < availableBytes; ch++, index++)
{
    byte drawnByte = dataBuffer[index];
    char drawnChar = (drawnByte < 32 || drawnByte > 126) ? '.' : (char)drawnByte;

    if (enteringMode == EnteringMode.Overwrite && (selection?.IsCharSelected(index + offset) ?? false))
        AddGlyph(drawnChar, charPositions[ch].Position.TextCharX, selectionRun);
    else
        AddGlyph(drawnChar, charPositions[ch].Position.TextCharX, regularRun);
}

regularRun.FillMissingAdvanceWidths();
selectionRun.FillMissingAdvanceWidths();

DrawGlyphRun(drawingContext, regularRun, SystemColors.WindowTextBrush, linePositions[line].TextStartY, pixelsPerDip);
DrawGlyphRun(drawingContext, selectionRun, SystemColors.HighlightTextBrush, linePositions[line].TextStartY, pixelsPerDip);
```

Comment: If any of the Draw methods causes a layout invalidation, that would not have an effect on the execution time of OnRender, since layout is done asynchronously. Do these methods set any properties of the control that affect layout, e.g. its width or height?

Comment: @Clemens, no, they don't Actually it looks like it is text drawing, what takes so much time, because if I comment out `DrawData` line, control starts responding a lot faster (despite performance statistics being constantly at ~3ms)

Comment: @Spook - any lessons learnt worth sharing? I'm curious how did you solve your issue.

Comment: @MaciekŚwiszczowski, yup, it turned out, that drawing text with regular DrawingContext methods was what slowed down the whole process. I added some information to the original post to show my solution (I didn't add an answer, because I actually didn't find solution to the original problem of profiling drawing process).

Comment: Also worth checking: https://github.com/dgrunwald/WPF-Text-Rendering-Benchmark

Comment: Very useful, thanks!